# How to prevent \settocdepth{chapter} lead to an empty list of listings

Tags: listings, memoir

Why does uncommenting the (IMHO innocent) call to `\settocdepth{chapter}` in the following MWE make the list of listings become blank? Or rather: what can I do to *both* preserve a chapter-only TOC for the appendix *and* keep the list of listings "alive"?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\lstlistoflistings
\newpage

\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption={Foo},label={lst:foo}]
Foo code
\end{lstlisting}
\newpage

%\settocdepth{chapter} % uncomment --> list of listings empty
\appendix
\chapter{Foo}
Bar
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\settocdepth{chapter}` causes

```
\changetocdepth{0}
```

to be written in the `.toc` file, so this setting continues when the list of listings is read in for typesetting.

Just reset it:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\settocdepth{subsection} 
\lstlistoflistings
\newpage

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption={Foo},label={lst:foo}]
Foo code
\end{lstlisting}
\newpage

\settocdepth{chapter} 
\appendix
\chapter{Foo}
\section{A section}
Bar
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I don't exactly understand why this is happening to a list of listings, but not an identically placed list of figures/tables.

Comment: @ojdo `\lstlistoflistings` uses the same framework as `\tableofcontents`, only changing the heading.